# How to detect focus on Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am having multiple input text in form and on ng-focus I am calling a method let's say GetFieldName().
I my angular.js how can I detect that method having the focus on first field or second.
How can I validate that withing getFieldName() method to get field which have focus on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to make angularJS directive to get the attrs 
or to make the validation 
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

This is solution with controller and $event to get the name attribute from element

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.text = "sample text";
  $scope.getName = function(event){
   $scope.text = event.target.getAttribute('name');
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div  ng-app="myApp">
<form ng-controller="formCtrl">
{{text }}
<input type="text" name="text1" ng-focus="getName($event)">
<input type="text" name="text2" ng-focus="getName($event)">
<input type="text" name="text3" ng-focus="getName($event)">
<input type="text" name="text4" ng-focus="getName($event)">

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Sotos for help.